# I tried to remove \r \n \t but there are still tabs

Tags: php

I tried

```
str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t"), ' ', $text);
```

It could strip new lines but there are still some tabs as you can see below. what's the preblem?

```
Metal Machine Music, Part I<br /> <br />     <br /> <br />     <br />     <br />     <br />     <br /> <br /> Metal Machine Music, Part II<br /> <br />     <br /> <br />     <br />     <br />     <br />     <br /> <br /> Metal Machine Music, Part III<br /> <br />     <br /> <br />     <br />     <br />     <br />     <br /> <br />
```

Comment: perhaps these are only multiple whitespaces?

Comment: Maybe that's the reason, and how do i remove them?

Comment: Alright, I've solved this problem by changing my code to 
$text = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t"," "), '', $text);
Thank you.

Comment: that strips ALL your whitespaces

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `preg_replace`

```
$str = preg_replace('/(\v|\s)+/', ' ', $str);
```

See http://codepad.org/2Dz1NmzD

Comment: does this remove from start and end of the string, or all the new lines, tabs?

Comment: This affects all occurences.

Answer (score 1):

this was better solution for me as suggested by LotusH in comments

```
$str = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t"," "), '', $str);
```